# Error loading font in a LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to load a font in a LWC via the following css code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'montserrat_custom';
    src: url('/resource/publicsite/MontserratRegular');
    src: url('/resource/publicsite/MontserratRegular') format('TrueType'),
        url('/resource/publicsite/MontserratRegular') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('/resource/publicsite/MontserratRegular') format('woff2'),
        url('/resource/publicsite/MontserratRegular') format('woff');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

The problem is that when the LWC loads and compile the CSS returns in the console the error `ERR_ABORTED 503 (Service Unavailable)`.

It's the whole day I am trying to solve this but I was not able to. What i have checked is the following:

- The resource is present at the right endpoint via the classic download link;
- The resource has public cache control;
- I tried to put the file extension in the css iIreported above but nothing changes;
- I tried tu use, instead of `/resource/publicsite/MontserratRegular`, `/sfsites/c/resource/publicsite/MontserratRegular` but nothing changes;

Something to report is that the LWC is used in a public site and it is directly used into it and additionally in the connectedCallback I load the style via the classic loadStyle function by salesforce.

Anyone has some idea that I can try to correctly loads the font? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to solve it!
Actually I had to load the fonts in the visualforce page and then apply the `font-family` in the css of the LWC page. The only tweak I had to do is that in the visualforce the font has to be loaded with `"{!URLFOR($Resource.NameOfResource, 'fontOfInterest.ExtensionOfTheFont')}"`

In my case I had to include in the visualforce the following code

> ```
> <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.publicsite, 'style.css')}"/>
> <style>
>     @font-face {
>         font-family: 'montserrat_custom';
>         src: url("{!URLFOR($Resource.publicsite, 'fonts/MontserratRegular.eot')}");
>         src: url("{!URLFOR($Resource.publicsite, 'fonts/MontserratRegular.eot?#iefix')}") format('embedded-opentype'),
>             url("{!URLFOR($Resource.publicsite, 'fonts/MontserratRegular.ttf')}") format('TrueType'),
>             url("{!URLFOR($Resource.publicsite, 'fonts/MontserratRegular.woff2')}") format('woff2'),
>             url("{!URLFOR($Resource.publicsite, 'fonts/MontserratRegular.woff')}") format('woff');
>         font-weight: 400;
>         font-style: normal;
>         font-display: swap;
>     }
> ```